# Nesting jquery's .append(), .each(), append() and keeping the first "this" reference

Tags: jquery

Please consider this code snippet:

```
            var ul = $(".list_b").find("li").remove().end();
        $.each(Sites, function (index, value) {
            ul.append(
                $("<li></li>")
                    .append(
                        $("<span></span>")
                            .addClass("img_b")
                            .css("background-image", "url(pin.png)")
                            .text(value.Name)
                    )
                    .append(
                        $("<div></div>")
                            .addClass("div_archives")
                            .each(value.Documents, function (index2, value2) {
                                this.append(
                                    $("<a></a>")
                                        .attr({ href: value.URL })
                                        .attr({ target: "_blank" })
                                        .html(value2.Name)
                                        .append(
                                            $("<img />")
                                                .attr({ src: "../img/icon_" + value2.Type + ".png" })
                                                .attr({ alt: "Archive " + value2.Tipo })
                                        )
                                )
                            }
                            )
                    )
            );
        });
```

And this json as the source object.

```
[   {
  "Id":1,
  "Name":"Rachel Weiss",
  "Color":"FF0000",
  "Symbol":"A",
  "Latitude":51.123123,
  "Longitude":12.131231,
  "Documents":[
     {
        "Id":1,
        "Name":"Document 1",
        "Ext":"pdf",
        "Type":"pdf",
        "URL":"http://www.google.com"
     },
     {
        "Id":2,
        "Name":"Document 2",
        "Ext":"doc",
        "Type":"word",
        "URL":"http://www.yahoo.com"
     },
     {
        "Id":3,
        "Name":"Document 3",
        "Ext":"xls",
        "Type":"excel",
        "URL":"http://www.amazon.com"
     }
  ],
  "Notes":[
     {
        "Id":0,
        "Texto":"test test"
     },
     {
        "Id":1,
        "Texto":"test test. test test"
     }
  ]},{
  "Id":2,
  "Name":"Natalie Portman",
  "Color":"00FF00",
  "Symbol":"B",
  "Latitude":51.123123,
  "Longitude":12.131231,
  "Documents":[
     {
        "Id":11,
        "Name":"Document 11",
        "Ext":"doc",
        "Type":"word",
        "URL":"http://www.google.com"
     }
  ],
  "Notes":[
     {
        "Id":10,
        "Texto":"test test. test test. test test."
     }
  ]} ... ]
```

The goal I'm tryin to achieve is to append the `<a></a>` block into the parent `<div></div>` block, but I can't find a way to reference the outer "this" object.

I know this must be a lame question, but I don't have any clue so every idea will be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

---

Aditional info:
Neither `this` nor `$(this)` works, both ways throws a runtime exception (Object doesn't support this property or method)

Comment: This is jQuery used to its fullest.

Comment: Have you considered using a template engine? I would recommend jQuery Templates: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Comment: @BoltClock: And features both Rachel Weiss and Natalie Portman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem seems to be that you're abusing the `each` function. There are two flavors: One for iterating through a matched element set, the other for iterating through array-like things (I'll call this the "utility" flavor).

With your usage, you're kind of hijacking the `<div>` element to use it for the utility flavor. It is the same as calling `$.each`, where `this` refers to the iteration value.

I think the proper solution to your problem would be to rethink the whole structure and not try to do everything in one huge chain of function calls.

Or better, use a template engine like jQuery Templates.

Comment: Hey man, this comment made me work late for two days rewriting the whole app, but the extra work was worth it every line. Now the page rendering are completely based in templates. The maintenance will be a lot more efficient with this approach. Thanks man, you made my week! :-)

Answer (score 3):

inside your needed this, you assign it to a variable, so it will be available after...

say you have

```
$("myelement").click(function() {
       var elementtoneed = this;
       $("myotherelement").load('sample.html', function() {
             $(elementtoneed).hide();
       });
});
```

So, that way you are saving the "this" element for future reference.

Comment: This generic solution does not really apply to what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Good idea, in fact i'm feeling stupid for don't think in this aproach before. Now the problem is to capture the variable inside the chain. Somebody suggested `($temp_div = $("<div></div>"))` but didn't worked....

Comment: Well is also truth that that code is almost unreadable...
@Rodrigo divide and conquer :)

Comment: indeed, this seems like a big PEBKAK. I will rewrite the whole function. Thanks.

Comment: pero estoy que te quito los puntos, solo por ser sansano :P

Comment: jaja, no seas rencoroso. = noma pa serte franco la U no me ha enseñado NADA que me haya ayudado a darte la respuesta :D

Comment: i like this "style" of jq…  it's the only kind that ever makes any sense to me.. enough with all the f-ing callbacks, already...